# Python lists combination

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations

I have multiple lists:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=[6,7]
C=[8,9,10]
```

The number of lists and the number of elements in each list can vary.

I am looking for a variable ABC which should contain a list that is a combination of all the values of all the lists, appending from C to B to A (appending from right to left) as shown below. Is there any way that I get this?

```
ABC=[168,169,1610,178,179,1710,268,269,2610,278,279,2710,........,578,579,5710]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a variant:

```
from itertools import product

ret = [int(f'{a}{b}{c}') for a, b, c in product(A, B, C)]
```

using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product).

---

if you need to have that for a variable number of lists you could do this:

```
lists = [A, B, C]  # D, E, F, ...]
ret = [int(''.join(str(item) for item in items)) for items in product(*lists)]
```

(alternatively have a look at [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm)'s version of this in the comments below).

Comment: Since the OP said the number of lists can vary, maybe a variant like `[int(''.join(map(str, w))) for w in product(*lists)]` which doesn't hardcode the fact there's three would be preferable.

Comment: @DSM you have got a point... will update accordingly. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this.

Here, you can pass any number of lists of integers (varying in numbers) to function and get the desired list of new numbers.

```
import itertools

def get_combined_number(*group):
    return int("".join(str(num) for num in group)) 

def get_numbers(*numbers_list):
    numbers = []
    for group in itertools.product(*numbers_list):
        numbers.append(get_combined_number(*group)) 

    return numbers

# Test case 1st
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=[6,7]
C=[8,9,10]

numbers = get_numbers(A, B, C)  # Any number of arrays/list can be passed
print(numbers) # [168, 169, 1610, 178, 179, 1710, 268, 269, 2610, 278, 279, 2710, 368, 369, 3610, 378, 379, 3710, 468, 469, 4610, 478, 479, 4710, 568, 569, 5610, 578, 579, 5710]

# Test case 2nd
D = [1, 4, 9]
E = [2, 7, 1729]
F = [8, 9,11]
G = [ 45, 92, 4, 12, 67]
numbers = get_numbers(D, E, F, G)
print(numbers) # [12845, 12892, 1284, 12812, 12867, 12945, 12992, 1294, 12912, 12967, 121145, 121192, 12114, 121112, 121167, 17845, 17892, 1784, 17812, 17867, 17945, 17992, 1794, 17912, 17967, 171145, 171192, 17114, 171112, 171167, 11729845, 11729892, 1172984, 11729812, 11729867, 11729945, 11729992, 1172994, 11729912, 11729967, 117291145, 117291192, 11729114, 117291112, 117291167, 42845, 42892, 4284, 42812, 42867, 42945, 42992, 4294, 42912, 42967, 421145, 421192, 42114, 421112, 421167, 47845, 47892, 4784, 47812, 47867, 47945, 47992, 4794, 47912, 47967, 471145, 471192, 47114, 471112, 471167, 41729845, 41729892, 4172984, 41729812, 41729867, 41729945, 41729992, 4172994, 41729912, 41729967, 417291145, 417291192, 41729114, 417291112, 417291167, 92845, 92892, 9284, 92812, 92867, 92945, 92992, 9294, 92912, 92967, 921145, 921192, 92114, 921112, 921167, 97845, 97892, 9784, 97812, 97867, 97945, 97992, 9794, 97912, 97967, 971145, 971192, 97114, 971112, 971167, 91729845, 91729892, 9172984, 91729812, 91729867, 91729945, 91729992, 9172994, 91729912, 91729967, 917291145, 917291192, 91729114, 917291112, 917291167]
```